# Message while loading images

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, slider

I have included the Nivo slider on my site, and it's working good but I would like to have some sort of message when the pictures are loading, because right now the footer gets pushed up which looks a bit messed up. Is there a quick way of adding a div or something when the image is loading?

[Here is the code](http://everlongdesign.com/#work). Just click on any of the projects.

Would really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: [Can I just post a link to my website?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHow about some arbitrary styles which are used until the image is loaded? Specifically, a minimum height and a background image to display until covered.

```
.nivoSlider img {
    background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Ajax-loader.gif") no-repeat center center;
    min-height: 300px; /* or whatever you consider a reasonable minimum */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added it but it doesn't seem to work for me... Is it working for you?

Comment: Doh. Bad class name on my part. Changed `.nivo-slider` to `.nivoSlider`. Also, as noted by Roman, the idea is to provide an indicator (an animated throbber image in this case) to give the viewer a sense that something is happening, rather than providing a message.

Answer (score 0):

Put a minimum height on the content that is loading. It will push the footer down.

CSS:
`min-height: 200px;`

Regarding a loading message, there are two ways to do it.

1. Replace the loading message when the images load (AJAX, see jQuery load() )
2. Place a loading message behind the images using `position: absolute`. Example: http://cssdesk.com/p3h9x

Edit: Luke's idea works, too, but it's only good for loading images (not text).

Comment: I tried his idea, but it's not working for me. Could you take a look and see what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: It's just two attributes, background and min-height. Here's a snapshot. http://i.imgur.com/dng5taY.png